# InputAccessoryView of UITextField disappears on rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uiinterfaceorientation, inputaccessoryview

I have a picker for inputView of a textfield, and a toolbar for inputAcessoryView of a textfield. When the orientation changes from portrait to landscape, the toolbar disappear and when i change it back, it reappears.

```
textField.inputView = picker
textField.inputAcessoryView = toolbar
```

Nothing else is being done in viewWillTransition or anywhere for that matter.

Answer (score -1):

Add this line of code to your `viewcontroller`

in swift 4.0

```
self.picker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

I was facing a similar issue this line of code resolved it.